# zsh function with `eval`

Tags: shell, zsh

I wrote a Rust program that parses a MySQL URI string and returns (prints) `mysql --host={host} --user={user}...`. I want to use it in a ZSH function (or alias, or whatever) such that I can just do `mysqlu $URI`, but haven't been able to get it to work.

I've tried:

```
function mysqlu {
    local u=$1
    eval $(mysql-uri-parser $u)
}
```

and

```
alias mysqlu="eval mysql-uri-parser"
```

The first one gives me `no such file or directory: $URI`. The second one just prints the command, which is close but no cigar. I can do `$(mysql-uri-parser $URI)` in the shell, and it works, but is still more typing than I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that the exact error message, or are you replacing the actual result of `$URI` with the literal string `$URI`? What's an actual output of `mysql-url-parser` that produces the error? I suspect you would want `eval "$(...)"` (if `eval` is even necessary), as unquoted command substitutions are still subject to word-splitting, unlike unquoted parameter expansions under default Zsh settings.

Comment: @chepner i'm replacing the `$URI` because it's private. the output of the command is `mysql --host=the correct host --user=the correct user` etc. i'll try your suggestions re: eval and word-splitting

Comment: Please provide accurate samples that don't reveal private information.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner had the solution:

```
function mysqlu {
  local u=$1
  eval "$(mysql-uri-parser $u)"
}
```